# store AM PM time string into TIME datatype in MySQL and retrieve with AM PM while display?

Tags: php, mysql, time, append

I m entering date in front end as **10:00 AM** , **12:00 PM** etc...( means 12 Hours format).
now I want to save that value in database in **time** datatype column. How do I save that AM PM  value into **time** datatype in MySQL and again want to display time appending **AM PM** on front end?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To insert:

```
# replace first argument of STR_TO_DATE with value from PHP/frontend
TIME( STR_TO_DATE( '10:00 PM', '%h:%i %p' ) );
```

To select:

```
# replace first argument with your time field
TIME_FORMAT( '22:00:00', '%h:%i %p' );
```

**EDIT:**
I'll just go ahead and presume you use mysql lib functions.

```
// first sanitize the $_POST input
// also, make sure you use quotes to identify the $_POST keys
$open = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST[ 'MondayOpen' ] );
$close = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST[ 'MondayClose' ] );

// this is the query, which should work just fine.
$sql = '
    INSERT INTO
        `table_lib_hours`
    SET
        `day_name` = "Monday",
        `day_open_time` = TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "' . $open . '", "%h:%i %p" ) ),
        `day_close_time` = TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "' . $close . '", "%h:%i %p" ) )
    ';

$result = mysql_query( $sql );
```

Then to retrieve the values:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT
        `day_open_time`,
        `day_close_time`,
        TIME_FORMAT( `day_open_time`, "%h:%i %p" ) as day_open_time_formatted,
        TIME_FORMAT( `day_close_time`, "%h:%i %p" ) as day_close_time_formatted
    FROM
        `table_lib_hours`
    WHERE
        `day_name` = "Monday"
    ';

$resultset = mysql_query( $sql );
```

This will return a result set where the formatted data is in the `*_formatted` fields

**EDIT:**
Adjusted `%m` (month) to `%i` (minutes). A thank you to Donny for the well spotted slip up.

Comment: First of: you shouldn't use $_POST directly in your queries... really. You should sanitize the values first. But to better help you: can you also show the PHP code where you execute this query? (Please update your question, rather then post a comment, if you will. Because that's easier to read. Thanks).

Comment: `TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "' . $open . '", "%h:%m %p" ) )` gives parse error

Comment: it should be
`TIME( STR_TO_DATE( '" . $open . "', '%h:%m %p' ) )`

Comment: when i run above code
it display error
        `day_close_time can not be null`

Comment: @I Like PHP: yes, if you use double quotes as the string delimiter for `$sql`. But as you can see in my example I use single quotes.

Comment: @I Like PHP: Make sure you use appropriate quoting. So, If you are using double quotes around the `$sql` string, then you need single quotes as string delimiters around values you insert in MySQL and vice versa.

Comment: The reason I use single quotes for PHP strings is that PHP parses variables in double quoted strings. I like to avoid this. I only even explicitly insert variables in PHP string by using the concatenation operator (the dot `.`).

Comment: Correction, should be:
`TIME_FORMAT( '22:00:00', '%h:%i %p' );` See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @Donny: oops, you're right. I'll adjust it. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql function DATE_FORMAT with %p parameter

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution
In your view-----  $('#schedule_time' + ).datetimepicker({pickDate: false, format: 'h:m A', minTime: new Date(), useCurrent: false, autoClose: false});

when insert into datbase ----'schedule_time' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post('schedule_time'))),

when show ---------