# How to insert time with am/pm format into the database

Tags: php, mysql

So im trying to insert a time using an input text field into a database table with data type TIME.

The format of time that I want to insert should be like this:

H:MM pm// example: 6:30 pm

The problem is the am/pm doesnt insert in my database table. 
Only the hour and minute.

Please give me idea how to solve this. 
Better with sample codes. Thanks.

Comment: Why you need to store time in that format? You can store time in a DATETIME field and show it the way you want...

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086313/insert-am-pm-from-front-side-and-store-in-time-field-of-mysql

Answer (score 7):

Data Type `TIME` is for storing time data type - that means no AM/PM. Store the data in Your database in 24 hour format and format it to 12 hour format with am/pm in PHP or MySQL using one of these:

PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime($mysql_column['time']);
$date->format('h:i:s a');
```

or:

```
$date = date('h:i:s a', strtotime($mysql_column['time']));
```

or MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%h:%i:%s %p', time) FROM table;
```

Comment: How do I format the time at first?I mean the user input of the time before saving into the database.

Comment: @Towki If the user is free to input whatever he wants, You would have to make a right data input validation. You could also create real-time JavaScript validation allowing user to input only numbers and a colon and only in this format: `00:00`. Then of course perform a sanitization and if You have a string like this: `18:59` or `08:12` etc You can just easily store this `string` into Your `TIME` column.

Answer (score 4):

Store the `TIME` as a standard format (`18:30:00`), and the format it however you want when you display it (Using `DateTime` objects or the date functions).

MySQL doesn't support extra formats when storing time data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add the jquery time picker value in your database with actual format in the database.

Here I have written some function

```
function update_time($time){
    $ap = $time[5].$time[6];
    $ttt = explode(":", $time);
    $th = $ttt['0'];
    $tm = $ttt['1'];
    if($ap=='pm' || $ap=='PM'){
        $th+=12;
        if($th==24){
            $th = 12;
        }
    }
    if($ap=='am' || $ap=='AM'){
        if($th==12){
            $th = '00';
        }
    }
    $newtime = $th.":".$tm[0].$tm[1];
    return $newtime;
}
$time = update_time($_POST['time']); //here I am calling the function now you can insert the value in db
```

you just have to call the function and insert the returned value in database.
And while printing that you can do something like that `echo date("h:i A",strtotime($time));`

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the field to a varchar. TIME cannot store it like that. However, keep in mind that storing it like you want to will make it more difficult to provide localized results if that is something you will eventually need. That is, timezone support becomes difficult if you are not storing the timestamp itself, but rather a user-friendly representation.

EDIT: Or, DATETIME works as well, as was pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: Dates and times belong in date or time (or DATETIME) fields. They should be stored as the proper type and converted for presentation.

Comment: Storing a timestamp as a string and converting that in PHP is, in my opinion, perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Until you need to do some sort of math operation, at which point it's not. If you didn't need a DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP type they wouldn't exist. (Didn't downvote, BTW; I just made a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime Object in PHP which has functions to create a time object from any format and also has a function to output a time in any format like so

```
<?php
     $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
     echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

You would be best changing the field type to 'VARCHAR (32)', and then writing the time with PHP.

```
Example: date('m/d/y g:i:sa');
```

Why do you want to store the am or pm anyhow? If you store the date/time as a unix epoch timestamp, you can format the date however you want in the program - not the database.

```
Example: time(); - Store this in an INT(8) field.
         date('m/d/y g:i:sa, $time()); - Output from DB like this.
```

Comment: Dates and times belong in date and time (or DATETIME) fields, not character fields. Convert them for presentation, not for storage.

Comment: This is true - I would use an int(8) data field instead.

Answer (score 0):

try .ToShortTimeString() after your date variable.