# insert and get Query for Time as AM/PM in JPA using java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086313/store-am-pm-time-string-into-time-datatype-in-mysql-and-retrieve-with-am-pm-whil)

**OR**

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT( `locStart`, '%h:%i %p' ) FROM locationtimes.
```

How could i achieve it using JPA

These are my Database Table entries

[image: Database table]

**My java Entity class**

```
package models;

package models;

import util.MyConverter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

/**
 * Created by abhinav on 11/2/15.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "locationtimes")
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Locationtimes.class)
public class Locationtimes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Column
    public Long locationId;

    @Column
    public String weekday;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    public Time locStart;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Time locEnd;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Time todayStart;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Time futureStart;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Time futureEnd;

    //@Transient
    @Column(name = "locStart")
    @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
    public String locStartString;

    //@Transient
    @Column(name = "locEnd")
    @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
    public String locEndString;

    @Column(name = "todayStart")
    @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
    public String todayStartString;

    //@Transient
    @Column(name = "futureStart")
    @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
    public String futureStartString;

    // @Transient
    @Column(name = "futureEnd")
    @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
    public String futureEndString;

    @Column
    public Long modifiedBy;

    @Column
    public Timestamp modified;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. it will be achieved by this process.

@Farrellmr Thanks for your support

```
package util;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.sql.Time;

/**
 * Created by aratan on 2/25/2015.
 */
@Converter
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, Time> {
    @Override
    public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(String s) {
        System.out.println("::::=========================convertToEntityAttribute ::" + s);
        return new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(Time time) {
        System.out.println("::::=========== convertToDatabaseColumn  ====== DateUtil.getFormattedTime(time) ::" + DateUtil.getFormattedTime(time));
        return DateUtil.getFormattedTime(time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I think you mean is you have time in a format -

> 14:21 --> 02:21 PM

And you want to maintain that format in the database?

The java.sql.Time object will store the time as 24hr format HH24:MM, in fact seconds since the epoch as its a wrapper around java.util.Date. This means the addition of AM/PM is a presentation issue through SimpleDateFormat -

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

You could either do this as a -

- Straight convert using SDF
- NamedQuery - to_char(,'HH:MM')
- AttributeConverter

Consider -

```
@Column
public Time locEnd;
```

If we convert this to a String of format HH:MM a -

```
@Column
 @Convert(converter = DateStringConverter.class)
public String locEndString;
```

Now create the converter class -

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class DateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter {

 private static final dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

 @Override
 public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(String datehhmma) {
  return dateFormat.parse(datehhmma);
 }

 @Override
 public String convertToEntityAttribute(String datehhmma) {
  return dateFormat.parse(datehhmma);
 }

}
```

Comment: yeah it's something like this, but my issue is regarding create a query that will fetch the time from db, and then it will convert it to the AM/PM format something like that. 

i want this
 SELECT TIME_FORMAT( `locStart`, '%h:%i %p' ) FROM locationtimes. 
from JPA

Comment: Ive added some suggestions

Comment: Yeah that all seems to be related to my query, if u have any example then please add them as well.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but it's not working .. code has exceptions.

Comment: Yeah the convertToEntityAttribute should have been a Time object. It was to show the principle of an AttributeConverter, not a perfect implementation because i dont handle exceptions either